# Conditionally counting the total number of matching rows for different dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif, conditional-statements

I need to monitor the **TOTAL** number of active female visitors by date. Tried to generate a formula by myself but failed and now ask your help. Data are as follows:

[image]

For each date in column A, the formula should show the total number of active female visitors. Active means that her

1. visit started before or on the same day of the date in column A
2. visit ends on the same day or after the date in column A

Here is the Excel file: [monitoring number of active visitors.xlsx](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/8bqwwgnr1n2d8j05h4oq8/monitoring-number-of-active-visitors.xlsx?rlkey=78c51u53ch3esky11y893w3ml&dl=1)

Comment: `COUNTIFS` should work, can you show us the formula you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$9;"<="&A2;$D$2:$D$9;">="&A2;$E$2:$E$9;"f")
```

Comment: Note: depending on your language settings, you may need to use commas (`,`) instead of semicolons (`;`)